# How would I modify this replace/regex from jquery.autocomplete so it only bolds the first match?

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I don't know enough to change the following so that it only puts `<strong>` around the first found string matching the term:

```
highlight: function(value, term) {
    return value.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\]){1}/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
}
```

This is from the jQuery autocomplete plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete or http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

By default if you type "a" in the field, the the following results would look like "**A**pple **A**te **A**nts" and I only want "**A**pple Ate Ants".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the last "gi" to "i" (the "g" tells it to replace all matches).

Comment: Thxs, I knew it was simple, just not up on my regex.